# How to exclude class in CSS selector with nth-child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I want to change the background color of elements coming after the 9th with *`:nth-child(n+10)`*, bypassing some elements that are already hidden with `display: none`.

I am using `.item:not(.hidden):nth-child(n+10)` selector but it is not working. When I use as an example `.item:not(.hidden):hover` selector, it is working.

This sample code:

```css
/********** just for ex. **********/
body {
  background-color: #333;
}
.item {
  height: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
/********** just for ex. **********/


.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.item:not(.hidden):hover {
  background-color: #00f;
}

.item:not(.hidden):nth-child(n+10) {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="item">1</li>
  <li class="item">2</li>
  <li class="item hidden">3</li>
  <li class="item">4</li>
  <li class="item hidden">5</li>
  <li class="item">6</li>
  <li class="item">7</li>
  <li class="item hidden">8</li>
  <li class="item">9</li>
  <li class="item">10</li>
  <li class="item hidden">11</li>
  <li class="item">12</li>
  <li class="item hidden">13</li>
  <li class="item">14</li>
  <li class="item">15</li>
  <li class="item">16</li>
  <li class="item">17</li>
</ol>
```

And I want:

[image]

[image]

Why `:nth-child(n+10)` does not affect the entire selection like `:hover`? And how can I fix it?

JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/qahaxihoja/edit?html,css,output

Comment: `:nth-child()` doesn't care about `class`. It counts *all* children of the same parent, whether you like it or not :-) `:hover`, well, that's not `:nth-child()`, `class` matters.

Comment: As @Michael_B stated, `:nth-child()` counts all children. I don't see a solution without modifying the HTML or using JS.

Comment: sure you can. You can specify a range with CSS nth child.

Comment: @Michael_B I have always hated naughty children. :(

Comment: Thanks @Dinei. I cannot do HTML editing but I can use JS code.